# Is this vintage altimeter from the Cuatro Vientos?

Tags: aviation-history, flight-instruments, altimeter

[image: altimeter]

My father who was a pilot, passed away some years ago and I have a vintage altimeter that he told me someone gave him.  They assured him that it belonged to the [Cuatro Vientos airplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuatro_Vientos_(aircraft)), but I'm not sure if this is the case. I've seen some pictures from the Cuatro Vientos's cockpit, and this instrument isn't very similar to the instruments in the photos I've seen. However, the painted text reads "Altura kilómetros", instead of "Altimeter". The text below that reads

> Pioneer Instrument Company
>
> Brooklyn New York
>
> 199-2044

I hope someone can help me find out if it was from that airplane. (Sorry for my English; I'm writing from Mexico City.)

Thanks in advance.

-Miguel Anaya

Comment: It may help if you provided a picture or two of your altimeter. [Edit] your post, then either click the "sun and mountain" icon above the text entry box and browse to the pic, or, just drag the pic into the text edit box. The SE servers will upload & host the image for you.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your question isn't clear, what is it you want to know? Bring some light about it is very broad.

Comment: We may be able to rule it out, but if it is at all similar, knowing if that exact altimeter was in that aircraft may be at best very difficult (without examining records showing serial numbers)

Comment: According to the Wikipedia article you link to, the aircraft disappeared without trace. It would seem unlikely, then, that this could be something from that aeroplane.

Comment: It could have installed and then removed sometime during the 4 years it operated before it disappeared.

Comment: The wreckage of the 'Cuatro Vientos' was found in 1996. The crew had been apparently robbed, killed and partially eaten up by the savage natives...  https://www.abc.es/archivo/periodicos/abc-madrid-19960312-75.html

Comment: The plane was a Bréguet 19. This is [a photo of the instruments panel](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k65549538/f836.item?lang=EN) of a similar aicraft (*Point d'Interrogation* used by [Costes and Bellonte](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNRhhUqKqn0)). This give an idea, but not sure two of these planes had the same panel.